# How to customize hostname checking for TCP/IP (not HTTP) TLS on Java8?

Tags: java, ssl, tcp

I'm using Java SE 8.

When I connect TLS (TCP/IP) server, I'd like to control (customize) hostname checking logic. For example, accepts only if hostname is matched, or always matched without any checking.
For HTTP, I can use `HttpsURLConnection`'s `setHostnameVerifier()` method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#setHostnameVerifier-javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier-

I'd like to do the similar thing on TCP/IP not HTTP. For example MQTT(S) on TCP/IP TLS.

I've read the following sites, but I couldn't get useful information.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SettingHostnameVerifier

Is there any convenient way to do that?

**edit 2017/10/24**

Some comments indicate that TCP/IP doesn't treat hostname.
True. I should rephrase my question.

Updated question is "how to write checking hostname function between the hostname of connect target and the hostname from server certificate?"

Connection target IP address is gotten using `getByName()`.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `SSLSession`, either via a `HandshakeCompletedListener` or inline from the `SSLSocket` after you connect it, get the peer certificate from the session, get the `subjectDN` from the certificate, and check it against the hostname you thought you were connecting to. If any of that fails, close the connection.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I achieved my goal. I had gotten confused that HTTP layer provides HostnameVerifier so I guessed that similar underlying functionality might exist. Now I understand that it doesn't exist.